# Can't access .mp4 files in resource folder iphone xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, bundle, movie

I have a file called fireFinalRotate.mp4, it's in the XCode project folder (both in XCode and in finder).  For some reason

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"fireFinalRotate" ofType:@".mp4"];
```

returns a nil.  Any thought?  I'm baffled.  Is it because it's a movie file?  That code's in viewDidLoad.

Comment: nvm.  got it.  had a .mp4 instead of mp4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going to say that the .mp4 is not a filetype but looks like you figured that out!

similar to how google thinks .edu is not a domain name but edu works when specifying what domains to search

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have included the file in the build target when you build the app?

Right Click on the "Groups & Files", then select the "Target Membership" Item. Make sure there is a check mark next to the file which would indicate it is included in the build target.